# Symfony2 best practice: redirect or trigger ajax-dialog from serverside

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have a symfony2-project with some ajax-dialogs. Now I found out, that it would be helpful to execute one of them directly after first login, so that it can't be forgotten.

What is the best practice for this?
Is there any other way than sending some kind of (hidden) tag with the generated page that forces the clientside-ajax to do that call immediately?

Comment: first of all, why do you need an ajax call after the first login? if some logic should happen after the first login, just override the login processing action and add the logic there. OR add a redirect to other action which executes the needed logic.

Comment: It's just the normal add-item dialog which should be started, because registration is useless without added items. I would have done a redirect, if if wasn't an ajax-dialog (what I don't want to change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution should still be a redirect. The action where the user after the registration is redirected should check if the user has items added and if not, show the dialog.

If you are using jQuery UI dialogs it is pretty easy.

```
// your temaplate (i use twig syntax)
{% if mustShowDialog %}
<script>
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
</script>
{% endif %}
```

You can see a demo for that [in the jQuery UI demo page](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

Comment: That should be a solution. I'm also using twig-view. Thx, will try it soon.

Comment: I just recognized, that I load the dialog via ajax when that link is clicked, so I have get do a nearer look at this possible solution.

Comment: i still think my solution would suit your needs.
1. User registers
2. User gets redirected to homepage.
3. Homepage checks if user has added items. If user has no items Dialog open script is printed.

Comment: Yes that should work. I 'only' have to change some of the dialog-handling (now, the dialog-view is loaded and rendered by ajax and just, when the user uses the add-button).

Comment: OK, I used this answer and made some changes to my dialog, which are shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354622/using-jquery-directly-in-html-and-twig THX