# Using jquery directly in html (and twig)

Tags: jquery, html, twig

### Short Version

Normally, I include jquery by writing a xy.js an including it in html/twig. This file than uses ready() or maybe load().

Are there any disadvantages, if I use jquery directly in a scipt-tag in twig and than - in some case - call  that function directly in an other script-tag directly in the twig-file?

### Long Version

While working on a problem ([if you like to look...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231020/symfony2-best-practice-redirect-or-trigger-ajax-dialog-from-serverside)), I found out, that I need some really basic knowing:

When include jquery via an own js-file, you can do:

`$(document).ready()` should be used to do things, when the DOM is loaded - OK

`$(document).load()` should be used, if js depends on resources, that may not be fully loaded at *ready()*

**But what**, if I include some code directly in the html (or twig in my case). I.e. that:

```
   ...
   {% block subtitleRechts %}
        {% if app.user %}
            <span id="add">
                <a href="{{ path('add') }}" alt="add Item">
                    <img height="20" src="{{ asset('bundles/myBundle/images/plus.png') }}"></a>
            </span>
            <script>
                $("#add a").each(function() {
                    var url = $("#add a").attr("href");
                    var $dialog = $('<div class="modalerDialog"></div>').
                        dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            width: 460
                        });

                    $(this).click(function() {
                        $dialog.load(url, null, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                            var title = $('#addPage').attr('title')
                            $dialog.dialog('option', 'title', title);
                        }).dialog('open');
                        return false;
                    });
                });
             </script>
             {% if whatever %}
                $("#add a").trigger("click");
             {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
    ...
```

This should add an ajax dialog to a link an in the case of '*whatever*' directly execute it.

This works local, **but I just don't know, if there are any disadvantages** (beside mixing twig, html an js in one file). In my case, there will also be an included js-file

Thx in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one disadvantage would be the difficulty to maintain the code. Perhaps the better solution would be to create a model, with single flags from server-side code like this:

```
//this one goes to separate .js file
function MyModel (){

        this.Init = function () {
            $("#add a").each(function() {
                var url = $("#add a").attr("href");
                var $dialog = $('<div class="modalerDialog"></div>').
                    dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        width: 460
                    });

                $(this).click(function() {
                    $dialog.load(url, null, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        var title = $('#addPage').attr('title')
                        $dialog.dialog('option', 'title', title);
                    }).dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }();
        this.TriggerClick = function(boolean) {
            if(boolean){
                $("#add a").trigger("click");
            }

        };
}

//this one stays on the page
var model = new MyModel();
model.TriggerClick({% whatever %});
```

Comment: 1. So my code would work? 2. An own model would be even better! Where would all this code be placed? Would the model be also definied in the twig-template?

Comment: 1. if it worked previously it should work this time too.
2. I ve marked what should go where in the answer. Add the js file only once: in template if it is related to the whole page or at least more than one place on the page or on single page if it is used there only.

Comment: OK, the code goes where I hoped it will go ;-) Thx. I Will try this soon.

Comment: it appeared that i made some mistakes in the markup when inserting the code. I've fixed it now.

Comment: I used this solution with some small modifies, main difference is 'caching' the link and implementing open(), which is just called, when if in twig complains. THX